# Amplify + AppSync not mutating object

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to setup an application using Amplify + AppSync/GraphQL without any prior knowledge on it, but now I'm facing so many issues that I'm questioning if it was a good decision.

I have added an AppSync API through Amplify

The queries are working fine for now, however, I'm having a hard time to make the mutations work, and worse, they don't give me any error.

The important parts of the schema of my database is as follow:

```
type Mutation {
    updateVideoOnDemand(input: UpdateVideoOnDemandInput!): VideoOnDemand
}

type ScriptRow {
    loop: Int
    timeStart: Int
    character: String
    text: String
    guessed: Boolean
}

input ScriptRowInput {
    loop: Int
    timeStart: Int
    character: String
    text: String
    guessed: Boolean
}

input UpdateVideoOnDemandInput {
    guid: String!
    thumbNailUrl: [String]
    startTime: String
    workflowStatus: String
    srcVideo: String
    hlsUrl: String
    dashUrl: String
    scriptUrl: String
    mp4Urls: [String]
    transcriptUri: String
    isLoadingLoops: Boolean
    documentKey: String
    initialOffset: Int
    videoOffset: Int
    scriptRows: [ScriptRowInput!]
}

type VideoOnDemand {
    guid: String!
    thumbNailUrl: [String]
    startTime: String
    workflowStatus: String
    srcVideo: String
    hlsUrl: String
    dashUrl: String
    scriptUrl: String
    mp4Urls: [String]
    transcriptUri: String
    isLoadingLoops: Boolean
    documentKey: String
    initialOffset: Int
    videoOffset: Int
    scriptRows: [ScriptRow]
}
```

Then, I have generated the local code using Amplify codegen tool
Which looks good

```
export const updateVideoOnDemand = `mutation UpdateVideoOnDemand($input: UpdateVideoOnDemandInput!) {
  updateVideoOnDemand(input: $input) {
    guid
    thumbNailUrl
    startTime
    workflowStatus
    srcVideo
    hlsUrl
    dashUrl
    scriptUrl
    mp4Urls
    transcriptUri
    isLoadingLoops
    documentKey
    initialOffset
    videoOffset
    scriptRows {
      loop
      timeStart
      character
      text
      guessed
    }
  }
}
`;
```

First I tried using the simple AWS API.GraphQL

```
        API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.updateVideoOnDemand, {
          input: {
            guid: video.guid,
            initialOffset: values.initial_offset,
            videoOffset: values.video_offset,
            workflowStatus: 'Test',
            isLoadingLoops: true,
            scriptRows: rows,
          }
        })).then(
          updatedVideo => {
            message.success('Saved');
          }
        ).catch(err => message.error('Error saving data: ' + err))
```

The mapping resolver for the mutation:

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "UpdateItem",
  "key": {
    "guid": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.guid),
  },

  ## Set up some space to keep track of things we're updating **
  #set( $expNames  = {} )
  #set( $expValues = {} )
  #set( $expSet = {} )
  #set( $expAdd = {} )
  #set( $expRemove = [] )

  ## Iterate through each argument, skipping keys **
  #foreach( $entry in $util.map.copyAndRemoveAllKeys($ctx.args.input, ["guid"]).entrySet() )
    #if( $util.isNull($entry.value) )
      ## If the argument is set to "null", then remove that attribute from the item in DynamoDB **

      #set( $discard = ${expRemove.add("#${entry.key}")} )
      $!{expNames.put("#${entry.key}", "${entry.key}")}
    #else
      ## Otherwise set (or update) the attribute on the item in DynamoDB **

      $!{expSet.put("#${entry.key}", ":${entry.key}")}
      $!{expNames.put("#${entry.key}", "${entry.key}")}
      $!{expValues.put(":${entry.key}", $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($entry.value))}
    #end
  #end

  ## Start building the update expression, starting with attributes we're going to SET **
  #set( $expression = "" )
  #if( !${expSet.isEmpty()} )
    #set( $expression = "SET" )
    #foreach( $entry in $expSet.entrySet() )
      #set( $expression = "${expression} ${entry.key} = ${entry.value}" )
      #if ( $foreach.hasNext )
        #set( $expression = "${expression}," )
      #end
    #end
  #end

  ## Continue building the update expression, adding attributes we're going to ADD **
  #if( !${expAdd.isEmpty()} )
    #set( $expression = "${expression} ADD" )
    #foreach( $entry in $expAdd.entrySet() )
      #set( $expression = "${expression} ${entry.key} ${entry.value}" )
      #if ( $foreach.hasNext )
        #set( $expression = "${expression}," )
      #end
    #end
  #end

  ## Continue building the update expression, adding attributes we're going to REMOVE **
  #if( !${expRemove.isEmpty()} )
    #set( $expression = "${expression} REMOVE" )

    #foreach( $entry in $expRemove )
      #set( $expression = "${expression} ${entry}" )
      #if ( $foreach.hasNext )
        #set( $expression = "${expression}," )
      #end
    #end
  #end

  ## Finally, write the update expression into the document, along with any expressionNames and expressionValues **
  "update": {
    "expression": "${expression}",
    #if( !${expNames.isEmpty()} )
      "expressionNames": $utils.toJson($expNames),
    #end
    #if( !${expValues.isEmpty()} )
      "expressionValues": $utils.toJson($expValues),
    #end
  },

  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_exists(#guid)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#guid": "guid",
    },
  }
}
```

The response mapping template:

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

The command seems to run successful, I get the updated video as result, and I can see the updated data on it... however some fields are not being updated on the database side... in this case the fields `isLoadingLoops` and `scriptRows` are not updated... and if I reload the page I get the old results again, if I check directly on DynamoDB instance I also see that the 3 first items are updated, but not the rest.

I've tried migrating the code to use AWSAppSync Client/Apollo.... still the error persists.

Any idea what could be causing it?

#### *UPDATE*

One thing that I'm not sure if they might be an indicator of something wrong:

When I go to AppSync console -> Queries, and then I click on the "Play" icon I see only 2 options to select from: *createVideoOnDemand* and *listVideoOnDemand*, I don't see the update there, it might be indicating an issue?

Comment: Can you share the mapping template on the API for that mutation?

Comment: @JeffBailey Done!

Comment: @danielfranca I set an API up similar to yours and tried using the AWS AppSync console with your input and things seemed to work just fine.  Can you test something like this against your api?

Comment: ```

```
mutation help {
  updateVideoOnDemand(input: { guid: "2", initialOffset: 1, videoOffset:2, workflowStatus: "Test", isLoadingLoops: true, scriptRows: [{
    loop: 1
    timeStart: 2
    character: "test"
    text: "test"
    guessed: false
  }]}) {
    guid
    isLoadingLoops
    initialOffset
    videoOffset
    workflowStatus
    scriptRows {
      loop
      timeStart
      character
      text
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @NathanQuinn I couldn't run this query in the console, just updated my question with more information.

Comment: @danielfranca Does the update mutation show up in the documentation section of the the console?  The options that display when you click the "Play" icon depend on the query that you have authored in the console editor, so this doesn't necessarily point to an issue.  If it's not there in the documentation section though, it means you haven't pushed the latest schema + resolvers to the cloud.

If you want to post your amplify project to GitHub, I can help you troubleshoot further and circle back here once we get this resolved.

Comment: @NathanQuinn Thanks Nathan, Sorry for the stupid question, but I can't find where is the documentation part on the AppSync console, I can see the following options in the left menu: Schema, Data Sources, Functions, Queries, Settings and Monitoring

Comment: @NathanQuinn It's already on Github, I just updated the question adding the url to the repository.

Comment: @danielfranca Not a stupid question.  Go to Queries -> On the right side of the page in the upper right hand corner you should see a link that says "< Docs".  When you click this it should expand a panel on the right that has Documentation information about your schema.  You can click on the types to link to drill down to further information about them.  I'll check out your GitHub link now.

Comment: @danielfranca looks like that link is private.  Feel free to add me if you'd like. 
 https://github.com/nathan-quinn

Comment: @NathanQuinn Sorry, forgot that it was private. Just added you

Comment: @NathanQuinn The documentation for the mutation is there

Comment: In this case there was a DynamoDB trigger that was overwriting the changes on the table.

Comment: I ran into this.  I triggered a mutation via AppSync direct after it failed to update from a Lambda or from Angular. `updateAsset(input: {id: "b34d3aa3-fbc4-48b5-acba-af616001630f", description: "AppSync"}` and it won't change the description field.  I can set new fields but I can't edit existing.  I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: Is there a solution for that? Runing in same issue when using update mutation with apollo client or in app sync console. Version counter is increased, new fields added but modified fields doesn,t touched.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has to do with how the app sync / amplify resolve conflicts. Conflict resolution is active if DataStore is enabled.

You may need this info when you use GraphQL from NodeJS on server side in addition to DataStore client on client side (for example lambda with IAM auth): https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js

**Including** the **_version** number works. Makes sense.

See also:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3237 (Update mutations GraphQL for new created models not working), see comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3237#issuecomment-584375936

**Not working example:**
[image]

**Working example:**
[image]

**Please note:**

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/how-it-works/q/platform/js#writing-data-from-the-appsync-console

> Writing data from the AppSync console
>
> DataStore is designed primarily for developers to not have to focus on
> the backend and let your application code and workflow create
> everything. However, there will be some use cases where you will use
> the AppSync console, a Lambda function, or other out of band processes
> to write data (such as batch actions or data migrations) and you might
> send GraphQL operations without the DataStore client.
>
> In these cases it’s important that the selection set of your GraphQL
> mutation includes all the required fields of the model, including:
> _lastChangedAt, _version, and _deleted so that the DataStore clients can react to these updates. You will also need to send the current
> object version in the mutation input argument as _version so that the
> service can act accordingly. If you do not send this information the
> clients will still eventually catch up during the global sync process,
> but you will not see realtime updates to the client DataStore
> repositories.

**An example mutation:**

```
mutation UpdatePost {
  updatePost(input: {
    id: "12345"
    title: "updated title 19:40"
    status: ACTIVE
    rating: 5
    _version: 7
  }) {
    id
    title
    status
    rating
    _lastChangedAt
    _version
    _deleted
  }
}
```